# What to do with a random variable when we know its mean and variance but does not know which distribution it is?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, combinatorial-game-theory, gambling

Let Y be a random variable with mean μ and variance σ^2 where the support is (0, ∞). Suppose you are offered to play a game where you choose a number z between (0, ∞). If a realization of the random variable y is greater than z then you win $z, otherwise you lose z dollars.

a. What value of z maximizes your expected gain? Can this maximum ever result in a loss? **following is my work:**

Let g(z) denote the expected gain,

g(z)  = z(1-F_{y}(z))-zF_{y}(z)

take diervative with respect to z,

g′(z)  = ((dg(z))/(dz))=1-F_{y}(z)-z∗f_{y}(z)-z∗f_{y}(z)-F_{y}(z)
 = 1-2F_{y}(z)-2z∗f_{y}(z)

let g′(z)  = 0,

1  = 2F_{y}(z)+2z∗f_{y}(z)

F(z)  = (1/2)-z∗f_{y}(z)

replace back to g(z)

g(z)  = z(1-(1/2)-z∗f_{y}(z))-z((1/2)-z∗f_{y}(z))
 = 2z²∗f_{y}(z)

F is the cdf, f is the pdf.

***I do not know how to use the mean and variance of Y, the problem is we do not know the distribution of Y.***

**Now part b:**

b. How large is the maximum expected gain for if Y ∼ exponential(λ).

**My work again,**

f_{y}(y)=λe^{-λy}

F_{y}(y)=1-e^{-λy}

and subs into g′(z)=0⇒1=2F_{y}(z)+2z∗f_{y}(z)

1=2(1-e^{-λz})+2z∗λe^{-λz}

and solve for z, I got z=((1-W((e/2)))/λ)≈((0.314923)/λ)

and replace this into g(z)=2z²∗f_{y}(z),

I got ((2e^{W((e/2))-1}(1-W((e/2)))²)/λ)≈((0.14477)/λ)

I do not think this is quite right.

Any suggestion will be appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you choose $z$ to be the median of the distribution, then your expected gain is $0$. So you can't be forced to lose.

Comment: @NeilThanks for help, can not we do better? To have a positive expected gain?

Comment: Why are you deleting nearly entirely your post?

Comment: @Hi Did, I just realised I should not post my working as this is a homework problem, I should not ask the details and I do not want others to copy it. I will add "homework" label if you think I should not delete, but I think I should just ask the question in the title, which is the part trouble me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume that $X$ is a continuous random variable.

The expected gain is, as you say LaTExlessly, $z(1-F(z))-zF(z) = z(1-2F(z)) = g(z)$. As Neil pointed out to you, this is $0$ when $z$ equals the median $m$. For
$z > m$, $F(z) > \frac 12$ and so $g(z) < 0$. Since $g(0) = 0$, the question is,
what is the behavior of $g(z)$ in the interval $(0,m)$? In this interval, $z>0$ and
$F(z) < \frac 12$ and so $g(z) > 0$. Thus $g(z)$ does indeed have a positive
maximum in $(0,m)$. The harder question is how can we determine the location of
this maximum from knowledge only of the mean and variance of $X$.

It is known that the difference between the mean $\mu$ and the median $m$ is no
larger than the standard deviation $\sigma$. See for example
[here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median#Inequality_relating_means_and_medians)
or [there](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev%27s_inequality#Cantelli.27s_inequality).  Thus, if
$\mu>\sigma$, we can choose $z = \mu-\sigma > 0$ and be guaranteed a nonnegative
(but not necessarily maximal) expected gain.

Comment: Thanks for help, yes I realised this, but since mean and variance come out of all data points of y, they are not saying anything about how likely each y happens, so I do not think we can determine pdf using these two parameters, there are many distributions having same mean and variance.